# funny interference between \baselinestretch and TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

The command `\baselinestretch` has a strange influence on Tikz Pictures, when it is not closed in a group (compare the two figures):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    \draw[very thick] (2,-0.2)+(30:1cm) arc (30:150:1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    \draw[very thick] (2,-0.2)+(30:1cm) arc (30:150:1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know that i should enclose the `\baselinestretch` in a group, but i found this effect funny ! :) (and i needed quite a long time to track this bug inside my documents...)

Comment: Note that adding `\selectfont` removes it! (thought I don't know why) Seriously, what is the question?

Comment: An the question ... is?

Comment: @nicolas roy: That is indeed a funny effect. It would be good if you could file a bug report at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=142562&atid=752792. You can reduce the example to something like `\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgf}
    
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{}
\begin{pgfpicture}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}
\pgfpatharc{0}{180}{5cm}
\pgfusepath{draw}
\end{pgfpicture}
\end{document}`, which should produce a circular arc, but doesn't.

Comment: @Daniel, @ienissei : well there is not exactly a question, since one should actually not use `\baselinestretch` in this way, but i think it shows that there is something strange in Tikz. On the other hand, this bug appear in a quite involved document class of mine, and i needed a long time to track it. So maybe if somebody encouters the same, he will know where to look for :)

Comment: To make it a question, one could ask for a temporary fix.

Answer (score 9):

Experimenting, it would appear that during the tikzpicture, `\baselinestretch` should be equal to whatever it was when the `\begin{document}` command was issued.  Moreover, it should not be long (no matter what `\baselinestretch` was at the start) - this is an issue with the `article.cls` since that contains the line `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{}` which makes it `\long`, whereas `latex.ltx` simply contains `\def\baselinestretch{1}` so is not `\long`.  The fact that `article.cls` makes it long is irrelevant by the time one gets into the document since `\selectfont` has implicitly made it not long again.

So until the bug is squished, here's a work-around.  I've tested it with various combinations of setting `\baselinestretch` with and without `\long` and it seems to survive them all, but as I don't really understand what's going on here I can't be held responsible for any damage caused by this strange behaviour.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\tikzbaselinestretch\baselinestretch}
\tikzset{every picture/.append style={
    execute at begin picture={%
      \edef\baselinestretch{\tikzbaselinestretch}%
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    \draw[very thick] (2,-0.2)+(30:1cm) arc (30:150:1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    \draw[very thick] (2,-0.2)+(30:1cm) arc (30:150:1cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Method incorporates suggestions from Jake, and experiments based on Altermundus' answer.)

---

Absolutely definitely a bug.  But it's deep.

The bug is actually in `\pgfmathsetlength`.  Quoting from the code:

> Furthermore, the font is setup before the assignment is
>    done, so that dimensions like 1em are evaluated correctly.

So within `\pgfmathsetlength` is a call to `\pgfmath@selectfont`.  This is an alias of `\selectfont` (as we're using LaTeX) which calls `\set@fontsize` if `\baselinestretch` is not what it was the last time that `\set@fontsize` was called[1].  Then `\set@fontsize` executes `\@defaultunits\@tempdimb#2pt\relax\@nnil`.  The upshot of is that if `\baselinestretch` has changed by some means *other* than a call to `\set@fontsize` then sometime in `\pgfmathsetlength`, `\@tempdimb` will get reassigned to something.

This, as Altermundus' hints at, causes problems for `\pgfpatharc`.  Within that code is a call to `\pgfpointpolar{\pgf@arc@angle}{\pgfutil@tempdima and \pgfutil@tempdimb}`.  In processing this, PGF calls `\pgfmathsetlength` but it does so **before** looking at the `\pgfutil@tempdima and \pgfutil@tempdimb` part.  So before we look at it, `\pgfutil@tempdimb` gets reassigned and we've forgotten what it originally was.

So the problem is that `\pgfutil@tempdimb` (which is an alias for `@tempdimb`) gets set to a new value before it is used.  Exactly how to fix this properly, I'll leave to the PGF team!  A simple solution would be that after loading TikZ (or PGF) one puts:

```
\makeatletter
\newdimen\pgfutil@tempdimb
\makeatother
```

This separates the link between `\pgfutil@tempdimb` and `\@tempdimb` at the expense of using up a dimen register.  An alternative would be to hack `\set@fontsize` so that the assignment to `\@tempdimb` occurred in a group.  Taking a leaf out of TikZ/PGF's many smuggling routines, we could do:

```
\def\set@fontsize#1#2#3{%
  \bgroup
    \@defaultunits\@tempdimb#2pt\relax\@nnil
    \edef\@smuggle{{\edef\noexpand\f@size{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}}}%
  \expandafter\aftergroup\@smuggle
  \egroup
    \@defaultunits\@tempskipa#3pt\relax\@nnil
    \edef\f@baselineskip{\the\@tempskipa}%
    \edef\f@linespread{#1}%
    \let\baselinestretch\f@linespread
      \def\size@update{%
        \baselineskip\f@baselineskip\relax
        \baselineskip\f@linespread\baselineskip
        \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip
        \setbox\strutbox\hbox{%
          \vrule\@height.7\baselineskip
                \@depth.3\baselineskip
                \@width\z@}%
        \let\size@update\relax}%
  }
```

(I think that works without making any extra global assignments, but I'm no expert.)

[1] In slightly longer form, `\set@fontsize` saves the current value of `\baselinestretch` as a macro, `\f@linespread` (which is not `\long`), and then `\let`s `\baselinestretch` to this macro.  So after calling `\set@fontsize` then `\baselinestretch` and `\f@linespread` are guaranteed to be the same.  If someone interferes with `\baselinestretch` in the meantime, even just to `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{whatever it currently is}`, then this comparison will fail and `\set@fontsize` gets called again.  In this case, `\baselinestretch` has been made `\long` because I didn't do `\renewcommand*`.

Comment: In testing Altermundus' answer, I saw that it's the setting at the start of the document (`\begin{document}`) that matters, not what happens when TikZ is loaded.

Comment: I don't think that `\long` or non `\long` makes a difference, as this has only to do with what arguments the command can accept.

Comment: @egreg: I bow to your superior expertise!  All I can say is that when I experiment, then having `\baselinestretch` as `\long` or not makes a difference.  My conjecture is that `\baselinestretch` is being compared with some "standard" and so that comparison fails if the `\long`/not`\long` match is wrong even if the value of the macro is correct.

Comment: Yes, inside `\selectfont` is `\ifx\f@linespread\baselinestretch\else\set@fontsize ... \fi` so there is a comparison of `\baselinestretch` with `\f@linespread` and `\f@linespread` is `\edef`ed to the current `\baselinestretch` (no `\long`).

Comment: You're right, of course: I didn't think to that. This is a real LaTeX bug! Using `\linespread` instead of `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}` would be safer.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the problem comes from

In latex.ltx there is

> ```
> \def\set@fontsize#1#2#3{%
>     \@defaultunits\@tempdimb#2pt\relax\@nnil
>     \edef\f@size{\strip@pt\@tempdimb}%
>     \@defaultunits\@tempskipa#3pt\relax\@nnil
>     \edef\f@baselineskip{\the\@tempskipa}%
> ```

or in pgfutil-latex.def there is

> ```
> \let\pgfutil@tempdima=\@tempdima
> \let\pgfutil@tempdimb=\@tempdimb
> ```

and in pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex

> ```
> \def\pgf@arc{%
>   {%
>   \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgf@arc@radius@a pt%
>   \pgfutil@tempdimb=\pgf@arc@radius@b pt%
> ```

Some Tex(perts) perhaps  may confirm this hypothesis.

**Update**

The problem disappears if I redefine `\def\pgf@arc{%`

I replace `\pgfutil@tempdimb` by `\mypgfutil@tempdimb`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  

\usepackage{tikz} 
\makeatletter
\newdimen\mypgfutil@tempdimb
\def\pgf@arc{%
  {%
  \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgf@arc@radius@a pt%
  \mypgfutil@tempdimb=\pgf@arc@radius@b pt%
  %
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@arc@local@angle@a\relax% 
  \pgf@xb=\pgf@arc@local@angle@b\relax%
  \advance\pgf@xb by-\pgf@xa\relax%
  \ifdim\pgf@xb<0pt\relax%
    \pgf@xb=-\pgf@xb\relax%
  \fi%
  \ifdim\pgf@xb=90.0pt%
    \def\pgfmathresult{0.55228475}%
  \else%
    \pgfmathparse{1.333333333*tan(.25*\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@xb})}% many thanks to Ken Starks
  \fi%
  \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfmathresult\pgfutil@tempdima%
  \mypgfutil@tempdimb=\pgfmathresult\mypgfutil@tempdimb%
  %.. controls +(\pgf@xa+90:\pgfutil@tempdima) and +(\pgf@xb-90:\pgfutil@tempdima) .. +(-(#1:#3)+(#2:#3))%
  % store first support vector in xa/ya:
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@arc@local@angle@a\relax%
  \ifdim\pgf@arc@local@angle@b>\pgf@arc@local@angle@a\relax%
    \advance\pgf@xa by 90pt\relax%
  \else%
    \advance\pgf@xa by -90pt\relax%
  \fi%
  \edef\pgf@arc@angle{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@xa}}%  
  \pgfpointtransformed{\pgfpointpolar{\pgf@arc@angle}{\pgfutil@tempdima and \mypgfutil@tempdimb}}%
  \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@pt@x%
  \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@pt@y%
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@path@lastx%
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@path@lasty%
  \advance\pgf@xa by \pgf@x%
  \advance\pgf@ya by \pgf@y%
  % store target in xb/yb:
  \pgfpointtransformed{\pgfpointpolar{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@arc@local@angle@a}}{\pgf@arc@radius@a pt and \pgf@arc@radius@b pt}}%
  \pgf@xb=\pgf@path@lastx%
  \pgf@yb=\pgf@path@lasty%
  \advance\pgf@xb by -\pgf@x%
  \advance\pgf@yb by -\pgf@y%
  \pgfpointtransformed{\pgfpointpolar{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@arc@local@angle@b}}{\pgf@arc@radius@a pt and \pgf@arc@radius@b pt}}%
  \advance\pgf@xb by \pgf@x%
  \advance\pgf@yb by \pgf@y%
  % store second support xc/yc:
  \ifdim\pgf@arc@local@angle@b>\pgf@arc@local@angle@a\relax%
    \advance\pgf@arc@local@angle@b by -90pt\relax%
  \else%
    \advance\pgf@arc@local@angle@b by 90pt\relax%
  \fi%
  \pgfpointtransformed{\pgfpointpolar{\pgf@sys@tonumber{\pgf@arc@local@angle@b}}{\pgfutil@tempdima and \mypgfutil@tempdimb}}%
  \advance\pgf@x by-\pgf@pt@x%
  \advance\pgf@y by-\pgf@pt@y%
  \pgf@xc=\pgf@xb\relax%
  \pgf@yc=\pgf@yb\relax%
  \advance \pgf@xc by \pgf@x\relax%
  \advance \pgf@yc by \pgf@y\relax%
  \pgfsyssoftpath@curveto{\the\pgf@xa}{\the\pgf@ya}{\the\pgf@xc}{\the\pgf@yc}{\the\pgf@xb}{\the\pgf@yb}%
  \global\pgf@path@lastx=\pgf@xb%
  \global\pgf@path@lasty=\pgf@yb%
  \pgf@protocolsizes{\pgf@xa}{\pgf@ya}%
  \pgf@protocolsizes{\pgf@xb}{\pgf@yb}%
  \pgf@protocolsizes{\pgf@xc}{\pgf@yc}%
  }%
}    


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    \draw[very thick] (2,-0.2)+(30:1cm) arc (30:150:1cm);
       \node[draw,align=right]{azerty\\qwerty} ;     
    \end{tikzpicture} 

    I recommend the setspace package. That package provides commands (singlespacing, 
onehalfspacing and doublespacing) and environments (singlespace, onehalfspace and 
oublespace) that allow to change the spacing within the document. You will find the documentation inside the setspace.sty file. (Stefan)


 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}  



      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]      
    \draw[very thick] (2,-0.2)+(30:1cm) arc (30:150:1cm);
    \node[draw,align=right]{azerty\\qwerty} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}  

     I recommend the setspace package. That package provides commands (singlespacing,
 onehalfspacing and doublespacing) and environments (singlespace, onehalfspace and 
doublespace) that allow to change the spacing within the document. You will find the 
documentation inside the setspace.sty file.  (Stefan) 

\end{document}
```

Solution (workaround)

First there is no problem if you use `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}` in the  preamble. Logically I've not tested but perhaps you can use `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}` in a group if you want to change locally.

Then you can remark that inside the nodes the baselineskip is also changed.

Finally a good idea is to use the setspace package like Stefan writes on his blog !

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tikz} 
%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
    \draw[very thick] (2,-0.2)+(30:1cm) arc (30:150:1cm);
       \node[draw,align=right]{azerty\\qwerty} ;     
    \end{tikzpicture} 

I recommend the setspace package. That package provides commands (singlespacing,
```

onehalfspacing and doublespacing) and environments (singlespace, onehalfspace and doublespace)
 that allow to change the spacing within the document. You will find the documentation inside 
the setspace.sty file. (Stefan)

```
  \doublespacing

I recommend the setspace package. That package provides commands (singlespacing,
```

onehalfspacing and doublespacing) and environments (singlespace, onehalfspace and doublespace)
 that allow to change the spacing within the document. You will find the documentation inside the setspace.sty file.  (Stefan)

```
      \begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2] 
    \draw[very thick] (2,-0.2)+(30:1cm) arc (30:150:1cm);
    \node[draw,align=right]{azerty\\qwerty} ;
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hypothesis 2/3rds confirmed.  The first two were absolutely right, but the issue is not in `\pgf@arc` but in `\pgfmathsetlength`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey ok thanks to confirm the origin of evil !